# Issue in receiving MultiCast packets in JellyBean devices

Tags: android, multicast

I am facing the following problem in receiving Multicast packets in devices running Android JellyBean 4.1

MultiCast packets are not received during the device is in Idle(Locked) state.

As suggested in most of the forums, I have tried WifiMultiCastLock, WifiWakeLock, WifiSleep Policy  etc.

But still my application is not able to receive multicast packets during idle state.

I tested the same installable in Android devices running ICS 4.0 or earlier versions. This issue is not occurring in those devices. I mean, the same application is receiving multicast packets even during idle(lock) state in ICS.

So, Is there anything I need to change for porting to JellyBean?

Please suggest the proper way to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance,
Pragadeesh